# LinqPad PopUp "Unable to invoke .Net Reflector ( is it installed ? )" Error Message

Tags: linqpad

I installed the following software into my laptop:

1. Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)
2. Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1
3. ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM
4. Copy *.XML to C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC
   3\Assemblies from another laptop which is full installed with Visual
   Studio 2011 Express
5. Copy *.XML to C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
   Pages\v1.0\Assemblies from another laptop which is full installed
   with Visual Studio 2011 Express
6. SQL Server Compact 4.0

I wrote the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    ActionResult
}
```

After pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, I get the following LinqPad message:

> Unable to invoke .Net Reflector ( is it installed ? )

How can I solve this problem without installing Visual Studio? I would appreciate step-by-step instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Reflector isn't part of the .Net Framework, but a product which is sold by Redgate and you can read more at their website [http://www.reflector.net](http://www.reflector.net/).

So, I guess the step by step instructions would either be :

- Don't press Shift-F1.

or

- Buy it (or download the trail)
- Install it.
- Restart Linqpad.

Linqpad also has an option 'Export to Excel', but that only works if you have Excel installed and the same applies with .Net Reflector.

Comment: The disassembler ought to be configurable to work with dotPeek and other Reflector alternatives.